# The number of worms (Moser's worm problem)

Tags: geometry, elementary-set-theory

The Moser's worm problem [[springer link](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02187832#page-1)]  asks for the region of smallest area that can accommodate every [plane curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_curve) of length 1. Curves can be rotated and translated and may be considered identical upto rotation and translation transforms.

What I ask is

> How many such curves of there, ie **What is the cardinality of the set of 'worms' *as referred to in Moser's worm problem***?

Comment: If I ever publish a paper in which I introduce a construction I refer to as a `crab' and discuss a problem about this, please do not ask about Jagy's crabs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cardinality of the set of plane curves of length 1 is the same as that of the continuum.  It is $\le$ the continuum because every such curve comes from a continuous function $[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^2$, and such a function is determined by its values on the rational numbers.  To see that it is $\ge$ the continuum, consider curves of constant curvature (sufficiently small such that they do not form a complete circle.)

The same argument works for equivalence classes of plane curves under rotations and translations, because curves of different constant curvatures are not equivalent.

Comment: That explains it, will the cardinality increase if we remove the equivalence constraints of rotation and translation.

Comment: @ARi No, it would still be the continuum.  This is what the first paragraph of my answer shows.